# Windows Shell Scripting: Check for batch options containing double quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file, arguments, quotes, space

Greetings, dear Experts!

I want to check the existense of parameter (or argument) sting at all in my batch script:

```
if "%*"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&goto :eof
```

This works fine if none of parameters is enclosed in double quotes. For example:

```
test.bat par1 par2 ... --- works
```

but

```
test.bat "par 1" par2 ... --- fails
```

My question are:

1) Is there any way to overcome this instead of requirement for use to use non-double-quoted symbol to specify "long" arguments and then use string substitution?

2) Can I ever use "if" to compare two strings containing both double quotes and spaces?

Your prompt and clear reply would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What do you expect to happen and what does happen?

Answer (score 2):

~ will strip the double quotes, but does not work on %*, but if you just want to know if there are no parameters, just checking %1 should be enough

```
if "%~1"==""
```

You might want to call setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS first to make sure extensions are on (required for ~)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Andres.
Here are two more pieces of code to check the existence and number of passed parameters:

```
set ArgumentString=%*
if not defined ArgumentString findstr "^::" "%~f0"&goto :eof
if "%ArgumentString:"=%"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&goto :eof
```

---

```
set NumberOfArguments=0
for /l %%N in (1,1,9) do (
  call set CurrentArgument=%%%%N
  if defined CurrentArgument set /a NumberOfArguments += 1
)
if %NumberOfArguments% NEQ %N% findstr "^::" "%~f0"&goto :eof
```

Here variable N contains needed number of parameters.

Hope this helps for somebody!

Comment: The latter way fails to count correctly with more than 9 arguments.

Comment: Thank you, Johannes!
However your method does not correctly process arguments with spaces, such as "aaa bbb"...

Answer (score 0):

Since Andrey's answer fails to correctly count arguments, here is a way that does work, even with more than 9 arguments (and it even perserves the original ones, so `%1` still points to the first one by moving the `shift`ing into a subroutine):

```
@echo off
call :get_num_args %*
echo %NumArgs%
goto :eof

:get_num_args
  set NumArgs=0
  :loop
  if not [%1]==[] (set /a NumArgs+=1) else (goto :eof)
  shift
  goto loop
goto :eof
```